# Need to extract the data between the double quotes in shell

Tags: shell

Input

```
<acc_details acct_no="00000" acct_nm="John"/>
<acc_details acct_no="00001" acct_address="109 BIRHN WAY " acct_nm="BARNS WY"/>
<acc_details acct_no="00002" acct_nm="BILL BAR" phne_nm="123456"/>
```

Expected output

```
acct_no,acct_address,acct_nm,phne_nm

00000,,John,
00001,109 BIRHN WAY,BARNS WY,
00002,,BILL BAR,123456
```

Comment: Do you mean the double COMMAs? There are no "quote" marks in your data strings.

Comment: Input Input <acc_details acct_no="00000" acct_nm="John"/>
<acc_details acct_no="00001" acct_address="109 BIRHN WAY " acct_nm="BARNS WY"/>
<acc_details acct_no="00002" acct_nm="BILL BAR" phne_nm="123456"/>

Output  acct_no,acct_address,acct_nm,phne_nm
00000,,John,
00001,109 BIRHN WAY,BARNS WY,
00002,,BILL BAR,123456

Comment: Please edit your question and add the detail as needed within the body itself. THe comments section is good for these back and forth items, but will get missed by many people who only read the main question. It is also helpful to use the markdown language available to format your post to indicate source code, etc. For help with the markdown, click the (?) at the top right of the 'Body' text box frame when editing your question. Thanks!

Comment: he added it, but did not format the xml as code ;-)

Comment: Need to get the values in a text file with all the columns as you can see number of columns are fixed but the column will be missing if the data isnt available in a row like acct_address & phne_nm missing in 1st row, phne_num missing in 2nd row, acct_address missing in 3rd row

Comment: Why in "shell"?
There are so many XML parsers available for so many programming languages (python, java, js, perl, ...). Why do you want to use shell for it?
Maybe you can use xsltproc for this (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14368347/convert-xml-file-to-csv-in-shell-script)

Answer (score 2):

Fix the `xml` file by adding a root tag:

```
<accounts>
<acc_details acct_no="00000" acct_nm="John"/>
<acc_details acct_no="00001" acct_address="109 BIRHN WAY " acct_nm="BARNS WY"/>
<acc_details acct_no="00002" acct_nm="BILL BAR" phne_nm="123456"/>
</accounts>
```

Then use an `xml` parser, [e.g. `xmlstarlet`](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/):

```
{
echo "acct_no,acct_address,acct_nm,phne_nm"
xmlstarlet sel -t \
    -m '//acc_details' \
    -v "concat(@acct_no,',',@acct_address,',',@acct_nm,',',@phne_nm)" -n \
    input_file
}
```

Output:

```
acct_no,acct_address,acct_nm,phne_nm
00000,,John,
00001,109 BIRHN WAY ,BARNS WY,
00002,,BILL BAR,123456
```

Comment: If xmlstarlet isn't available then how to go about it

Comment: Install it :-) How to do that depends on your system, many OS will offer it from their package system e.g., for Ubuntu it's in `universe` repository, so you can simply install it using `apt`.

Comment: I understand but i have to go through approvals which will take lot of time. I need a quick fix. Thanks for understanding

Comment: Have a look at the [python solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1912434/how-do-i-parse-xml-in-python) (don't only look at the accepted answer, e.g. `xmltodict` seems pretty easy).

Comment: Need script in only shell

Comment: Running `python -c "my_python_script"` is as much shell as running `grep`, `awk` or `xmlstarlet`.